# import module within loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have one file, let's call it foo.py. It does a couple of things, including sending some data over a serial port and emailing the response that comes back.

I have another file, which looks something like this:

```
iteration = 0
while True:
    iteration += 1
    // do some stuff here every time
    if iteration%5 == 0:
        import foo
    time.sleep (100)
```

I'm aware there are some broader problems here with the elegance (or lack thereof) of an independent counter, but putting that aside - the serial transmission / email only works the first time it's triggered. Subsequent loops at a multiple of 5 (which will trigger the modulo 5 == 0) do nothing.

Does my imported version of foo.py get cached, and avoid triggering on subsequent runs? If yes, how else can I call that code repeatedly from within my looping script? Should I just include it inline?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: can you explain why you'd want to import it more than once?

Comment: Basically. Put your code from `foo` into a function, your import at the start of the file, and call `foo.name_of_function()`

Comment: Thanks for the question VenomFangs. NightShadeQueen is correct - it's just a block of code I wanted to re-execute multiple times. Makes more sense for it to live in a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have access to `foo.py`, you should wrap whatever you want to run in `foo.py` in a function.  Then, just import `foo` once and call the function `foo.func()` in the loop.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296036/does-python-optimize-modules-when-they-are-imported-multiple-times) for an explanation of why repeated imports does not run the code in the file.

Comment: Oh of course - this makes complete sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `import foo` with

```
if 'foo' in dir(): # if it has already been imported
    reload(foo)
else:
    import foo
```

Not quite sure, but this should work.
*Edit:* Now I am sure.

Comment: Yes, it should work, but ___please___ don't do this. The `reload()` function should really only be used during development, when you're working in an interactive interpreter and you need to reload a module that you've modified. See [the docs for reload()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload). Note that in Python 3, `reload()` is _not_ a built-in, you have to import it from [imp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html#imp.reload) or [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload).

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes, you are right, but I actually think the OP is aware of that.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I wasn't aware this is an option and it's good to know too :)