# Import package from another installation directory for a particular method

Tags: python-3.x, sys

I wanted to run a python method with another version of `random_word` package. Basically, I have 2 versions of this package installed, one is there in `'/home/arya/Documents/random-word'` and the other is in `'/home/arya/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages'`. So, just to try out, I started with this piece of code.

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
import random_word
print(random_word.__file__)
del random_word
sys.path[-2],sys.path[-1] = sys.path[-1],sys.path[-2]
print(sys.path)
import random_word
print(random_word.__file__)
```

On running,

```
(myvenv) arya@arya-HP-Notebook:~/Desktop$ python test.py
```

it prints

```
sys.path :  ['', '/home/arya/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/home/arya/Documents/random-word']
location of random_word package:  /home/arya/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/random_word/__init__.py
sys.path :  ['', '/home/arya/Documents/random-word', '/home/arya/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
location of random_word package:  /home/arya/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/random_word/__init__.py
```

I have one installation of `random_word` package in `/home/arya/Documents/random-word` and the other one is there in the site-packages directory of my virtualenv.

So, my doubt is even after I change the order of the directories in `sys.path`, why my python program only finds the `random_word` in `site-packages`?

**Note:** If I change the order before the first `import random_word` statement, then python picks up the `random_word` installed in `/home/arya/Documents/random-word`. I couldn't understand why doesn't it work for the earlier case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what you are seeing is the module cache. When you are importing a module, Python will cache that module internally, so a subsequent import can just refer to the same module instance again. Python does [this optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/296036/216074) to prevent having to recompile modules again. This also effectively makes modules singletons, since there can only ever be a single instance of it.

By calling `del random_word`, you are just removing a reference to that module but that will not unload the module. So when you later import the `random_word` module again, Python does not actually look inside of the import path again but will just reuse the module it already has.

That is why changing the path order *after* having imported the module once will not have any effect.

There are some questions covering the idea of [explicitly reloading already imported modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/437589/216074) but I would generally recommend not to rely on that. The cache is there for a good reason, and you should name your modules accordingly, so that you do not run into conflicts you get from having the same module name in multiple locations.

Comment: Very well explained. Thanks @poke.