# Import same python module if I call a function of different file

Tags: python, import, module

I was wondering what happens if I call a module on different file, which imports the same python module that is already imported on the main call, is it imported twice? If yes, how can I prevent it? What is recommended way for this?

On the following example `time` module is imported on the both files. As alternative solution, I passed `time` module as an argument to the module call that is located on different file.

---

Example:

**hello.py**

```
from module import module
import time

time.sleep(1)
module();
```

**module.py**

```
import time; # Already imported in hello.py

def module(): #{
    time.sleep(1)
    print('hello')  
#}
```

---

**Alternative:** I am passing `time` module as argument into `module()` function that is located under `module.py`.

**hello.py**

```
from module import module
import time

time.sleep(1)
module(time);
```

**module.py**

```
def module(time): #{ 
    time.sleep(1)
    print('hello')
#}
```

Comment: "call a module on different file"? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296036/does-python-optimize-modules-when-they-are-imported-multiple-times) might help. As a side note, I'm really not keen on the commented-out braces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A module is only located and executed once, no matter how many times it is imported.  It's stored in the `sys.modules` dict, so subsequent imports are just a dictionary lookup.  There's no reason to try to avoid multiple imports of the same module.