# Does Python cache imported files?

Tags: python

Consider the following:

a.py

```
foo = 1
```

b.py

```
bar = 2
```

c.py

```
import a
kik = 3
```

d.py

```
import a
import c
def main():
    import b
main()
main()
```

---

- How many times is a.py loaded?
- How many times is b.py loaded?

---

More generally, I would like to know how is Python handling imported files and functions/variables?

Comment: https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/ `The first thing Python will do is look up the name abc in sys.modules. This is a cache of all modules that have been previously imported.`

Comment: You can run `strace -e trace=file python3 d.py` to see which files python is accessing and in which order

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does python optimize modules when they are imported multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296036/does-python-optimize-modules-when-they-are-imported-multiple-times)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both `a` and `b` are loaded once. When you import a module, its *content* is cached so when you load the same module again, you're not calling upon the original script for the import, done using a "finder":

- https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0451/#finder
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder

This works across modules so if you had a `d.py` of which import `b`, it will bind to the same cache as an import within `c.py`.

---

Some interesting builtin modules can help understand what happens during an import:

- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#importsystem

  > When a module is first imported, Python searches for the module and if found, it creates a module object 1, initializing it.

  Notably here the **first** import, all imports after follow the `__import__`. Internal caches of finders are stored at `sys.meta_path`.
- [https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#**import**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__)

You can leverage the import system to invalidate those caches for example:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module

> If you are dynamically importing a module that was created since the interpreter began execution (e.g., created a Python source file), you may need to call invalidate_caches() in order for the new module to be noticed by the import system.

---

The `imp` (and `importlib` py3.4+) allows the recompilation of a module after import:

```
import imp
import a
imp.reload(a)
```

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload

  > Python module’s code is recompiled and the module-level code re-executed, defining a new set of objects which are bound to names in the module’s dictionary by reusing the loader which originally loaded the module.
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html