# Python does not see new changes in files

Tags: python, git, caching, import, git-clone

When I am adding new functions to a file I can't import them neither if I just run the script in terminal or if I launch `ipython` and try importing a function there. I have no `.pyc` files. It looks as if there is some kind of caching going on. I never actually faced such an issue even though have been working with various projects for a while. Why could it happen?

What I see is the following: I launch `ipython` and the functions that were written long time ago by other programmers can be imported fine. If I comment them out and save the file, they still can be imported without any issues. If I write new functions they can't be imported.

The directory is `git` directory, I cloned the repo. Then the new branch was created and I switched to it. Python version is `3.7.5`, and I am working with virtual environment that I created some time ago which I activated with `source activate py37`.

I don't know whether its important but I have an empty `__init__.py` in the folder where script is located.

The code (I don't think its relevant, but still):

```
import hail as hl
import os
      
class SeqrDataValidationError(Exception):
    pass

# Get public properties of a class
def public_class_props(cls):
    return {k: v for k, v  in cls.__dict__.items() if k[:1] != '_'}

def hello():
    print('hello')
```

`public_class_props` is an old function and can be imported, but `hello` - can't.

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you've successfully cloned the project into your machine, If it is a problem with importing functions or methods from a different .py file, please check the points below.

1. check your working directory, whether you're in the same directory where the .py file/module with functions/methods exist.
2. once you import any function/method from a module, even you comment out the function/method and save the .py file, it won't affect the already imported functions as long as you re-import it.
3. as long as it is a problem of importing from your own .py files, the virtual environment has nothing to do with that.

EDITED:

check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57346840/8340027), it may give you some information about how caching works while importing python modules.

Comment: I relaunch ipython and rerun python, so its not 2. Other old functions are imported fine, so its not 1 either.

Comment: __init__.py would be empty only. it just says that the directory is a python package, nothing to worry about it. if you could put some code, it would help us understand the situation better.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that `PYTHONPATH` was set to a wrong folder. We had two folders with the project: old and new, similarly named, with identical project structure (but different file contents) and `PYTHONPATH` was set to the old project.