# How to cache python imports better?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As has been well-documented ([SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57346840/does-python-cache-imported-files?noredirect=1&lq=1), [Python import documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html), etc), python caches its imports and generates compiled .pyc files so that you only have to import files once. However, not all of the information is cached; I don't understand exactly how the caching works. I would like to more completely cache the imports so that files that take a long time to import can be sped up. For example, say I have these files, which look like this:

```
main.py
/src
    mysrc.py
```

**main.py**

```
import time
start = time.time()
from src.mysrc import TesterClass

print ("elapsed:", time.time() - start)
```

**mysrc.py**

```
import time
time.sleep(2)  # SLEEPING FOR 2 SECONDS HERE

class TesterClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Then if I call main.py from the command line, it will show that just over 2 seconds elapses every time, no matter if the .pyc files have already been generated.
It seems like there would be a way to keep track of the class if it has already been imported, so that subsequent calls to import the class would be much quicker.
Is this possible?

Comment: Try importing TesterClass twice in main.py. Put some timing print functions before, in between and after the two imports.

Comment: Statements at module level are always executed. `time.sleep(2)` is at module level.

Comment: Note that byte-compiling a Python file does not mean executing it. `time.sleep(2)` is not executed during compilation to a `.pyc` file.