# Why does Python allow a module to import itself?

Tags: python, python-import

In a simple Program in `BugTest.py`:

```
from BugTest import *

print("Hello World")
```

**note my error in importing BugTest.py from BugTest.py**

Here is the output:

```
Hello World
Hello World
```

My question is: **Why doesn't this cause a compile error?** Is this a bug in Python?

Why does it only import twice, rather than enter an infinite loop?

Comment: *"note my error"* -- Sorry, what error? Do you mean the output wasn't what you were expecting?

Comment: Once you import something, next time you import it, it doesn't run the file again, it just references the module of same name that was previously imported, instead of running it again

Comment: @Matiiss Erm, Python does have a compiler, but it's not often used directly. Python source code is compiled to byte code, then the byte code is run on the Python virtual machine. A `SyntaxError` can be considered a compile error.

Comment: @wjandrea right, well, good to know now, had to research this a bit, thought everything was done by the interpreter...

Comment: I could have sworn there is a canonical duplicate for this, but I have no idea how to search for it at the moment.

Comment: @Karl Maybe [python import multiple times](/q/37067414/4518341)?

Comment: @wjandrea I feel that a module importing itself is objectively an error(at least in terms of readability). I hate absolutes but I cant think of a time where you would want all the code in your module to run twice, and would opt to do it this way as opposed to a loop.

Comment: @wjandrea that looks more like a duplicate of the canonical that I referenced in my answer.  Simply knowing that there is a module cache only gets you part of the way there. A canonical for this question would need to talk about the special `__main__` name for modules too.

Comment: I guess I feel that it's an obviously-bad enough thing to do I'm surprised Python didn't catch it with an error

Comment: Python is **generally** not in the habit of nannying the programmer on "obviously-bad" things. "That's not the right way to do it" is the responsibility of the community (and documents like PEP 8 and PEP 20), not `python.exe`.

Comment: @Matiiss probably the only *purely* interpreted language people really use today are shell languages like `bash` etc

Comment: @JacobWaters the code won't run twice, unless it is the entrypoint (and this is, IMO a wart, because essentially, the entry point goes into the module cache as `"__main__"` so it would get re-imported

Comment: @Jacob Ah yeah, it certainly feels like bad style. But it's not an error, cause "error" means the program tried to do something that's explicitly not allowed.

Answer (score 4):

> Why doesn't this cause a compile error?

Because it's completely valid syntax. The **only** error (absent a problem in the Python runtime itself, such as running out of memory or failing to find the source code) that can occur at compile time in Python is `SyntaxError`. Names are only resolved at runtime.

That said, it's also completely valid at runtime.

> Why does it only import twice, rather than enter an infinite loop?

`from BugTest import *` means - roughly - "[look for an existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296036) module named `BugTest`; if not found, find and load `BugTest.py`, create a module object from it named `BugTest`, and put it in the module cache. Then, copy all the names from the `BugTest` module into the current module (overwriting any existing names)."

When you run the program, Python creates a module object from the `BugTest.py` code, and ([very usefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/)) gives it the special name `__main__`. Then it runs the top-level code, triggering the `import` statement. Now it creates another module object from the `BugTest.py` code, giving it the usual name of `BugTest`. That module's top-level code runs as well; but when it tries to `import`, a `BugTest` module is already in the module cache.

Answer (score 2):

You executed

```
$ python BugTest.py
```

which asked for two statements to run,
an import and a print.

The pair of statements ran exactly once.

The first statement performed an `import`,
which has the side effect of printing a line.

Then the second statement, a `print`,
printed a line as requested.

Everything happened according to plan.

---

It is usually considered undesirable for
an import to have side effects
such as `print()`.
In this case, of course,
it makes perfectly good sense
during debugging.

---

Once imported,
a module appears in a hash table
and will not be re-imported again.
So attempting a double `import`
here would not provoke three lines of output.

That is, having done (a possibly time
consuming) `import x`,
we won't see `x` imported again.
If top-level, or any transitive
dependencies imported by top-level,
asks for `import x`, it is simply
skipped, as a cache hit.