# Python: Importing pandas into main and modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a python script with a structure that looks like the following:

```
/
  __init__.py
  main.py
  /modules
    fbm.py
```

I am attempting to split some functions out from main.py into fbm.py and then import fbm.py as a module using.

```
sys.path.extend([f'{item[0]}' for item in os.walk("./app/modules/") if os.path.isdir(item[0])])
import fbm
```

This is working.

What I am having trouble with is where I need to call pandas (or another import) from a module.
I'm currently importing pandas in main.py with `import pandas as pd`.
When I call the function from `fbm` an error is thrown as soon as it hits a reference to `pd` stating that `NameError: name 'pd' is not defined`. `pd` is defined in main.py, but not fbm.py. It thus works in main, but not in fbm.

So, my question is: **Is it good and appropriate to `import pandas as pd` in both the main.py and each module which requires pandas?**

- Will this have an impact on memory usage, ie loading multiple copies of pandas
- is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: You need to import `pandas` in all files which use it, there is no other way.

Comment: Modules can't reference variables declared in main. If a module needs pandas, it needs to import it itself.

Comment: There's little impact on memory. Pandas is only loaded once, it's just added to the module's namespace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does python optimize modules when they are imported multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296036/does-python-optimize-modules-when-they-are-imported-multiple-times)

Comment: Thank you all. The explanation is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is appropriate to `import pandas` (or any other library) in both the main script and each module that requires it. This is a common practice and ensures that each module can function independently, which makes the code more modular and easier to maintain.

Regarding your concerns about memory usage: Python is smart enough to handle imports efficiently. When a module is imported for the first time, it's loaded and cached in the `sys.modules` dictionary. So, if the same module is imported again (even with a different alias), Python will use the cached module instead of loading it again and again. So, there won't be any significant impact on memory usage.